# How do I host a localhost on my server with Mac Terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, localhost

I've been hosting a localhost on my Mac with CSS, HTML, and JS. To do this i just navigate to my file with `cd Desktop` followed by `cd filename` , and then I do `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to host my server on my localhost. I know that this only works for the person hosting the server, but I'd like to host it on my local network, so anyone that goes to `localhost:8000` will see it. (I'm fine with it not being `localhost:8000`, in fact, I'd love a custom name.)

Thank you

**-A**

Comment: Unless everyone on your network is logged onto your computer, `localhost` not resolve to the machine running your server.

Comment: does that mean that if I do the `login` command on someone else's mac, and log into mine I can see my host? @juanchopanza

Comment: From that login session, yes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, localhost is a "domain" name if you like. Most of the times it resolves to 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback ip address(e.g. points back to your computer).
I am going to assume you are using python 2.x

So here we go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

addr = ("0.0.0.0", 8000) #host to everyone

serv = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(addr, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

serv.serve_forever()
```

Save that to a python script and run with:

```
python myfile.py
```

If you are using python 3 then go with :

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0 8000
```

Now for someone else to access your server through your local network, you have to give them your machine's ip.
To do that run:

```
ifconfig |grep inet
```

You should get something alone the lines of:

```
inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 etc etc
```

Now anyone on your local network can use your server by typing

```
192.168.1.2:8000
```

in their browsers

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to expose localhost to other people is using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), available via `brew install ngrok` or that link. 
In your example above, running `ngrok 8000` would allow other people to access the server you've got hosted. It's worth noting, obviously, that this isn't restricted to your local network!

Perhaps a better option (if all you're doing is hosting static HTML, CSS & JS) would be to set up a simple Apache instance. The default config should probably work just fine, and people could then access your page using your computer's local IP e.g `192.168.0.10:8000`, or whatever port you set up.

EDIT: As the other answerer pointed out, SimpleHTTPServer will do everything Apache does... You just need to give people your machine's local IP!